# Invalid column name when db colation is Vietnamese CI AS

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have problem with column name  when I use **Vietnamese_CI_AS** collation on database. Problem Column name is CL_IntRealID varchar(128)

I make some investigation a Problem is coused by replacing 't' by 'T' or 'R' by 'r'

```
/*this types of upper and lower case work well*/
select CL_IntRealID,CL_TParam,CL_RealID from HamSFA.Codelist  -- original column name
select CL_INtREAlID from HamSFA.Codelist  
select cl_intRealid from HamSFA.Codelist
select CL_IntRealID,CL_TPaRam,CL_realID from HamSFA.Codelist 


/*when I change T or R character I receive Invalid column name error */
select CL_InTRealid,CL_realID from HamSFA.Codelist -- Invalid column name result, if "t" is replace by "T"
select cl_IntrealID from HamSFA.Codelist -- Invalid column name result, if "R" is replace by "r"
```

Problem ocured only with column CL_IntRealID.

Is there any problem with combination or character t and r in column name?
How can I avoid this problem?
Error don't occurred if I use db with different collation

Comment: I guess column names are already defined in your database. You just need to use them with exact matching case.

Comment: Colation of db is Case insensitive it should work with upper or lower case.

Comment: Problem is that in Vietnam lanuage is Tr character so when you create tableor column wich contain  'Tr' and select 'TR' this is different character. Same like if you create table A in English collation and select table B. Table not exists.

Comment: What I was trying to say is, When i have already defined a column which contain 'Tr' then why should i call it with 'TR' or Similar to english when i haev created a table as A why should i call it as B?